# Updating data from form using jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

There are many  topics with this title, but none have helped me resolve my issue. I am new to MVC and jQuery, so my guess is there is something syntactically wrong with my approach. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have a web application where I have an upper and a lower section on my page (both divs). My goal is to select a record in the top div (user list) and have the bottom section display a list of challenge questions that the user can fill in answers for. The list below is injected in using jquery based on the record selected in the top grid. Here's the code I am using to do this.

View - javascript:

```
function editModeratorSecurity(aPersonId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Admin/GetAdvSecurity/' + aPersonId,
        type: 'POST',
        progress: showModSearchProgress(),
        success: function (result) {
            AdvancedSuccess(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            AdvancedFailure(result);
        }
    });
}

function showModSearchProgress() {
    $("#ModeratorDetail").hide();
    $("#progressMod").show();
}

function endModProgress() {
    $("#progressMod").hide();
    $("#ModeratorDetail").show();
}

function AdvancedSuccess(result) {
    $('#ModeratorDetail').html(result);
endModProgress();
}

function AdvancedFailure(result) {
    endModProgress();
}
```

Controller:

```
    public PartialViewResult GetAdvSecurity(string id)
    {
        //ID is the iD from the person table
        PersonModelBuilder pmb = new PersonModelBuilder(CurrentSession.AccountId);
        PersonEditModel pers = pmb.GetPersonToEdit(new Guid(id));

        if (pers != null)
        {
            AdvancedSecurityModel sec = new AdvancedSecurityModel();
            UserModelBuilder umb = new UserModelBuilder();

            //Need to get the ID from the login table - using the email address
            UserModel selUser = umb.CurrentUser(pers.EmailAddress);
            //Need to get the challenge questions/answers for the selected users
            List<UserQuestionModel> theQ = umb.GetUserChallengeQuestions(selUser.LoginId);

            sec.theUser = selUser;
            sec.theQuestions = theQ;

            return PartialView("_UserChallengeQuestions",sec);
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView("_UserChallengeQuestions", new AdvancedSecurityModel());
        }

    }
```

So - this call to the controller returns the partial view and I am populating the list of questions using the following code in the partial view:

```
    @model AdvancedSecurityModel

    <form id="frmChallengeQuestions" class="inlineForm">
    <div style="min-height: 100px; max-height: 400px;overflow: hidden" >
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="right"><input type="button" value="Save Changes" onclick="ValidateAndSave()"/>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @{
                        string sInstruction = "";
                        string isChecked="";
                        string isDisplay = "none";
                        if (Model.theUser.SecondLevelAuthReqd)
                        {
                            isChecked = "checked='true'";
                            isDisplay = "";
                            sInstruction = "<br>&nbsp;Please answer <strong>at least 5</strong> of the questions below to set up this feature...";
                        }
                    }
                    &nbsp; 2nd Authentication&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="2ndAuth" onclick="javascript:ToggleQuestions()" @isChecked/>
                    <br />&nbsp;Checking this means that you will be required to answer a random challenge question from the questions you answer in the<br/>&nbsp;list below each time you log in.
                    <span id="spnExplanation"></span>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <div id="theQuestionsandAnswers" style="display: @isDisplay; max-height: 175px;overflow-y: scroll" >

                        <table width="100%">
                            @{
                                if (Model.theQuestions != null)
                                {
                                    int iCount = 0;
                                    foreach (UserQuestionModel ques in Model.theQuestions)
                                    {
                                        string theAnswer = "";
                                        iCount += 1;
                                        if (ques.UserAnswer != null)
                                        {
                                            NLxCommon.Encryption enc = new NLxCommon.Encryption();
                                            theAnswer = enc.Decrypt256(ques.UserAnswer);
                                            enc.Dispose();
                                            enc = null;                                        
                                        }
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>@ques.QuestionText</td>
                                            <td><input id="Answer_@iCount" type="text" value="@theAnswer" /></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input id="UserQuestionId_@iCount" type="hidden" value="@ques.UserQuestionId">
                                                <input id="QuestionId_@iCount" type="hidden" value="@ques.QuestionId">
                                                <input id="UserId_@iCount" type="hidden" value="@Model.theUser.LoginId">
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>

                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        </table>                
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
```

In the loop, I am naming my controls -  input id="Answer_@iCount" -  Where iCount is the number of the question - from 1 to x.

The input button is an attempt to save the changes I made to the answers of the questions listed. The javascript function is listed below.

```
    var numQ = @Model.theQuestions.Count;
    function ValidateAndSave() {
        var NumAnswers = 0;

        for (i=1;i<=numQ;i++) {
            var answer = "#Answer_" + i.toString();

            var theAnswer = $(answer).val();
            if (theAnswer != "") {
                NumAnswers += 1;
            }
        }

        if (NumAnswers < 5) {
            alert('You must answer at least 5 questions to enable this feature');
            return false;
        }

        //Answered the right number of questions so SAVE
        for (j=1;j<=numQ;j++) {
            var uAnswer = "#Answer_" + j.toString();
            var uUserQid= "#UserQuestionId_" + j.toString();
            var uQuestionId= "#QuestionId_" + j.toString();
            var uUserId = "#UserId_" + j.toString();

            var theUAnswer = $(uAnswer).val();
            alert(theUAnswer );

            var theuUserQuestionId = $(uUserQid).val();
            alert(theuUserQuestionId );

            var theuQuestionid = $(uQuestionId).val();
            alert(theuQuestionid);

            var theuUserId = $(uUserId).val();
            alert(theuUserId );

            $.ajax({
                url: '/admin/savechallengequestion',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    UserQuestionId:  theuUserQuestionId.toString(),
                    LoginId: theuUserId.toString(),
                    QuestionId: theuQuestionid.toString(),
                    UserAnswer: theUAnswer.toString()
                },
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                //progress: showModSearchProgress(),
                success: insSuccess(data),
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        }


    }
```

My goal with this was to loop through the answers, sending one ajax call per transaction .If someone could tell me how to do this in one call I'm willing to listen :)

The alerts all pop, showing the proper data, but when I get to the ajax call, the progress function gets called, but the ajax call never makes it to the server - I never even see it in Fiddler - like nothing happened. The controller method and the model expected are listed below - havent filled out the controller method yet - still trying to get this to fire.

Model:

```
    public class UserQuestionModelSave
    {
        public string UserQuestionId { get; set; }
        public string LoginId { get; set; }
        public string QuestionId { get; set; }
        public string UserAnswer { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveChallengeQuestion(UserQuestionModelSave aQuestionInfo)
    {
        UserModelBuilder umb = new UserModelBuilder();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                return Json(new { success = true });

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return Json(new { success = false });
            }
        }

        return Json(new { success = false });

    }
```

If anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate it - this has stumped me for almost 2 days now....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ajax request doesn't fire, then you should check console for javascript errors. BTW, there is no "inSuccess()" function in your code, which you use in this ajax call.

Comment: I did not include the insSuccess function in my code - just the one with the ajax call - but it is there.

Comment: If the `insSuccess` function itself returns a function based on some global variable `data`, then sure, it might work. However, I'm guessing that you're simply forgetting to wrap the success function appropriately, as you did in the View JavaScript. IOW, `success: function (data) { insSuccess(data); },`...

Comment: Mike - that was the issue - I copied the ajax call from a class where the function was overloaded and did not change it to be a standalone function - the call now shows up in Fiddler - Thanks - I cant mark it as the answer because you added this as a comment and not an answer. Thanks again :)